# extracting an int from a string using isdigit

Tags: c++

I'm needing to parse a string and convert the first series of digits into an integer.

Here is the function:

```
    int get_int (string to) {
    string temp = "";
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < to.length(); i++) {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)to[i])) {
            cerr << to[i];
            temp = temp+to[i]; 
        }
        i++; 
    }
    return stoi(temp); 
}
```

and I'm passing it: "test: 19764\n". However, I'm getting the output 174 (both in print and return value). What is going on?

Thanks,
Cameron

Comment: Notice the i++ at the end of the loop

Comment: Ah! I've stared at this for over an hour. Thank you.

Comment: Enable more compiler warnings and it will warn you about typos like this. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HehPwixnJCTxlcgR

Comment: This does something different from converting the first series of digits into an integer (also after the i++ fix).

Comment: For the next, don't "stare at it for over an hour". Do one of the following: Use a debugger, build in system messages (like at the beginning of the loop print the value of i and every time something important happens, the values of the variables before and after) or do the rubber duck method (take a rubber duck and explain to it what every line of code does and why it is needed - not a joke, actually helps).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: extra condition increment

```
int get_int (string to) {
  string temp = "";
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < to.length(); i++) { <--
    if (isdigit((unsigned char)to[i])) {
        cerr << to[i];
        temp = temp+to[i]; 
    }
    i++; <--
  }
return stoi(temp); 
}
```

If I really had to do this using `isdigit` I would rather go with something along the lines of

```
int get_int(string to) { // Assumes a base10 representation
  int value = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < to.length(); ++i) {
    if (isdigit(to[i])) {
      cerr << to[i];
      value = value * 10 + (to[i] - 0x30);
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

Not sure why you need to output the digits to `cerr` though.